# Highlight only matching text within a string (JQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight only matching text within a string at any point.

I have an input box which filters the results. Originally this worked fine to highlight the FIRST character, but the remit has changed to highlight the text within a string at any position.

Fiddle: [Highlight matching text](https://jsfiddle.net/SIDESTEAL/3d3xkLpL/)

It *filters* perfectly as it should, but highlights letters starting at the front, not the matching ones. I tried to use indexOf valThis to sort it out but I was probably doing it wrong.

Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

```
$('#box').keyup(function () {

var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase();
var length  = this.value.length;

$('.objType').each(function () {
    var text  = $(this).text(),
        textL = text.toLowerCase(),
        //n = textL.indexOf(valThis);
     var htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(length);

    if(textL.includes(valThis))
    {
      $(this).html(htmlR).show()
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
var htmlR = '<b>' + text.substr(0, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(length);
```

says "take `length` characters from the beginning of the string." You want to start with the first *matching* character, so you need to know where that is. So you want `String#indexOf`, not `String#includes`.

You also want to save the original text so you can compare against that, not against the text updated by the previous filter operation:

```
// Grab the original text
$(".objType").each(function() {               // ***
    $(this).data("original", $(this).text()); // ***
})                                            // ***
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var length = this.value.length;

  $('.objType').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).data("original"),      // ***
      textL = text.toLowerCase(),
      index = textL.indexOf(valThis);         // ***

    if (index !== -1) {
      var htmlR = text.substr(0, index) + '<b>' + text.substr(index, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(index + length); // ***
      $(this).html(htmlR).show()
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d3xkLpL/3/), snippet:

```js
// Grab the original text
$(".objType").each(function() {               // ***
 $(this).data("original", $(this).text()); // ***
})                                            // ***
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase();
  var length = this.value.length;

  $('.objType').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).data("original"),      // ***
      textL = text.toLowerCase(),
      index = textL.indexOf(valThis);         // ***

    if (index !== -1) {
      var htmlR = text.substr(0, index) + '<b>' + text.substr(index, length) + '</b>' + text.substr(index + length); // ***
      $(this).html(htmlR).show()
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

span {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Filter results" id="box" type="text" />

<span class="objType" id="item1">Accepted Event Relation</span>
<span class="objType" id="item2">Case Status Value</span>
<span class="objType" id="item3">External Data Source</span>
<span class="objType" id="item4">Navigation Link Set</span>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. It clearly works as needed but I'm going to take some time to digest the changes so I fully understand _why_ it works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use a combination of `indexOf`, `RegEx` and `substring` to find and highlight the position of the word in each string.

See Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sxk7qj40/

```
$('#box').keyup(function () {
  const valThis = this.value;
  const length  = this.value.length;

  $('.objType').each(function () {
    const text  = $(this).text();
    const textL = text.toLowerCase();
    const position = textL.indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase());

    if (position !== -1) {
      const matches = text.substring(position, (valThis.length + position));
      const regex = new RegExp(matches, 'ig');
      const highlighted = text.replace(regex, `<mark>${matches}</mark>`);

      $(this).html(highlighted).show();
    } else {
      $(this).text(text);
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

You would not want to hardcode your `substring` position at 0, as this will always begin at the start of the string regardless.

Instead, you need to use `indexOf`, which will return the starting position. You can then use that in the substring to find the starting point that you want to `replace`. Note that `indexOf` will return `-1` if not found, hence the `if` statement.

Where to end though? Well, this will come in as a combination of the start position we already have + the string length you just typed.

> **NOTE:** For my own convenience, I used some *es2015* features like const and template literals, but you can't use *es2015*, simply run it through Babel,
>   or manually replace these parts with var and string concatenation
>   respectively.

Hope this makes sense?

e.g. ES5 safe:

```
$('#box').keyup(function () {
  var valThis = this.value;
  var length  = this.value.length;

  $('.objType').each(function () {
    var text  = $(this).text();
    var textL = text.toLowerCase();
    var position = textL.indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase());

    if (position !== -1) {
      var matches = text.substring(position, (valThis.length + position));
      var regex = new RegExp(matches, 'ig');
      var highlighted = text.replace(regex, '<mark>' + matches + '</mark>');

      $(this).html(highlighted).show();
    } else {
      $(this).text(text);
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
It does non-destructive copying

```js
$('#box').keyup(function () {
    var valThis = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        length  = this.value.length;

    $('.objType').each(function () {
        var text  = $(this).text(),
            textL = text.toLowerCase(),
            textStart = textL.indexOf(valThis),
            textEnd = textStart+valThis.length;
            //n = textL.indexOf(valThis);
         var htmlR = text.substring(0,textStart)+'<b>' + text.substring(textStart,textEnd) + '</b>' + text.substring(textStart+length);
        
        if(textStart!=-1) {
          $("#"+this.id+"r").html(htmlR).show()
         $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
         $("#"+this.id+"r").empty();
         $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
input[type="text"] { 
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 110%;
    margin:10px;
    padding: 5px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
span{
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  margin:10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Filter results" id="box" type="text" />

<span class="objType" id="item1">Accepted Event Relation</span><span id="item1r"></span>
<span class="objType" id="item2">Case Status Value</span><span id="item2r"></span>
<span class="objType" id="item3">External Data Source</span><span id="item3r"></span>
<span class="objType" id="item4">Navigation Link Set</span><span id="item4r"></span>
```