# how to highlight a word inside html tags without highlighting tags in vue

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2

i have a tag with v-html that renders a html text and shows it,like this:

```html
<div v-html="htmlText"></div>
```

i write this code for highlighting text and it works on normal text:

```js
Vue.filter('highlight', function (word, query) {
  if (query !== '') {
    let check = new RegExp(query, "ig");
    return word.toString().replace(check, function (matchedText, a, b) {
      return ('<strong class="mark">' + matchedText + '</strong>');
    });
  } else {
    return word;
}
```

```html
<div v-html="$options.filters.highlight(htmlText, myWord)">
</div>
```

i want to  highlight a word inside this text without highlighting html tags.
please help.
thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight only matching text within a string (JQuery/Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328094/highlight-only-matching-text-within-a-string-jquery-javascript) **or** [Vue js text highlight filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839608/vue-js-text-highlight-filter)

Comment: it's not duplicate...

Comment: my htmlText is like this:
<div>hjbsdhbdhbvj<span>vgfbhj<a>duhsbc</a>bvsdjbh<div>fuhsb<div>cdbh</div>vfshb</div><p>vfdvd</p></span></div>
and none of the tags has specific class or id or ...
and they are unknown

Comment: Then it is not very clear what you're asking. Could you clarify what you're looking for? Maybe post a sample of the HTML that is not working with the function you specified. At the moment, based on the information provided, it seems you are telling us that your function does not work (which, at the moment it does not - click on the run code snippet). These factors are causing some confusion about what you are trying to do/having issues with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not opposed to external dependencies, you could use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

It allows for highlighting text using a RegExp, and can work across HTML tags. Here is an example of how it might be used with Vue:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    // The html to highlight
    html: '<div>Hello <span>this </span>is <span>some </span>text</div>',
    
    // The html with highlighting
    highlightedHtml: '',
    
    // The search term to highlight
    search: 'Hello'
  },
  watch: {
    // When the search term changes: recalculate the highlighted html
    'search': {
      handler: function() {
       // We create an element with the html to mark. Give it a unique id 
        // so it can be removed later
        let id =  'id' + (new Date()).getTime();
        $('body').append(`<div id="${id}" style="hidden">${this.html}</div>`);
        
        // Create a Mark instance on the new element
        let markInstance = new Mark('#' + id);
        
        // Mark the text with the search string. When the operation is complete,
        // update the hightlighted text and remove the temporary element
        markInstance.markRegExp(new RegExp(this.search, 'gmi'), {
          done: () => {
            this.highlightedHtml = $('#' + id)[0].innerHTML;
            $('#' + id).remove();
          },
          acrossElements: true,
        });
     },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.0/mark.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div>/ <input type="text" v-model="search"> /gmi</div>
  <div v-html="highlightedHtml"></div>
</div>
```